# What estimator to use in random effects model?

Tags: meta-analysis

Can you recommend any reads/webpages that elaborates when and what estimator to use in random effects model when conducting a meta-analysis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor/metafor.pdf) for the metafor() package (Viechtbauer, 2010) in R provides some good suggestions, as metafor() includes 9 different methods of estimating random-effects models. Viechtbauer recommends the references below as good sources for getting up to speed on the ins-and-outs of each estimator, and I've updated to include the references recommended by the commenters below. I would start with [Veroniki et al.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jrsm.1164/full) (2016; open-access).

**References**

DerSimonian, R., & Kacker, R. (2007). Random-effects model for meta-analysis of clinical trials: An update. *Contemporary Clinical Trials*, *28*, 105–114.

Langan, D., Higgins, J., & Simmonds, M. (2017). Comparative performance of heterogeneity variance estimators in meta‐analysis: a review of simulation studies. *Research Synthesis Methods*, *8*(2), 181-198.

Raudenbush, S. W. (2009). Analyzing effect sizes: Random effects models. In H. Cooper, L. V. Hedges, & J. C. Valentine (Eds.), *The handbook of research synthesis and meta-analysis* (2nd ed., pp. 295–315). New York: Russell Sage Foundation.

Veroniki, A. A., Jackson, D., Viechtbauer, W., Bender, R., Bowden, J., Knapp, G., ... & Salanti, G. (2016). Methods to estimate the between‐study variance and its uncertainty in meta‐analysis. *Research Synthesis Methods*, *7*(1), 55-79.

Viechtbauer, W. (2005). Bias and efficiency of meta-analytic variance estimators in the random- effects model. *Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics*, *30*, 261–293.

Viechtbauer, W. (2010). Conducting meta-analyses in R with the metafor package. *Journal of Statistical Software*, *36*(3), 1-48. URL: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v36/i03/

Viechtbauer, W., López-López, J. A., Sánchez-Meca, J., & Marín-Martínez, F. (2015). A comparison of procedures to test for moderators in mixed-effects meta-regression models. *Psychological Methods*, *20*, 360–374.

Comment: Furthermore, there are two quite recent review articles published that recommend to use either the Paule-Mandel or restricted maximum likelihood estimator:

Veroniki, A. A., et al. (2016). Methods to estimate the between-study variance and its uncertainty in meta-analysis. and 

Langan, D., Higgins, J. P. T., & Simmonds, M. (2016). Comparative performance of heterogeneity variance estimators in meta-analysis: A review of simulation studies.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that the very comprehensive review by Veroniki et al is available under a Creative Commons licence DOI: 10.1002/jrsm.1164 whereas the other one is behind a paywall

Comment: Thanks all--updated the response to include suggested readings by User33, and recommend the Veroniki et al. paper in particular given that (as mdewey points out) it is OA.