# What Heterogeneity/Between-Study Variance Estimator to use in a Reliability Meta-Analysis/Reliability Generalization Random Effects Model?

Tags: meta-analysis, reliability, heterogeneity, reliability-generalization, reliability-meta-analysis

This is an extension of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323093/what-estimator-to-use-in-random-effects-model) but for reliability generalization studies.

Could anyone recommend a between-study variance / heterogeneity ([image]) estimator and method for computing confidence intervals that are suited to reliability meta-analyses of coefficient alpha? (or perhaps correlation coefficients if that is not known).

I have been through the resources listed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323093/what-estimator-to-use-in-random-effects-model) but they generally refer to (standardized) mean differences rather than reliability coefficients. Furthermore, most of the reliability generalizations studies I have seen use a variety of estimators without justifying their choices.

If it is simply a case of generalizing from the resources mentioned above, then I would guess that the Paule and Mandel method (which is equivalent to the Bayes method) would be appropriate because it does not require distributional assumptions (assuming the alpha coefficients might not be transformed) and shows several favourable properties compared to other estimators, particularly under increasing levels of heterogeneity (see [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jrsm.1164) and [here](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2019-60513-001)).

As an aside, the `metafor` package is well-equipped to employ a range of estimators, including the Paule and Mandel method (see the [metafor document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor/metafor.pdf), p. 318).